# How to map through an array and dynamically set key and values inside mapped array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-map

I have an array arr with the below format

```
data:{
  result: [Array]
 }
```

I am mapping an array and setting key and values to form new array like this.

```
const userData= arr.map((user) => ({
userid : user.data.result[0].info.uid,
termStat: user.data.result[0].info['attr'].termStat

}));
```

This will give me the userData array as

```
[{
userid: 'y74',
termStat:[[Object]]
}]
```

How can I make this to the below format. Placing key as the value of userid.
This is the expected result

```
{
  y74: { termStat: [[Object]]
 }
```

Comment: `const userData= arr.map((user) => { [user.data.result[0].info.uid]: { user.data.result[0].info['attr'].termStat } })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array map function always returns an array. If you want to return a map from the input array **Array.reduce()** function will be helpful. Something like:

```js
const arr = [{ data: { result: [{ info: { uid: 'y74', attr: { termStat: [[{}]] } } }] } }];

const userData = arr.reduce((result, user) => {
    const key = user.data.result[0].info.uid;
    const termStat = user.data.result[0].info['attr'].termStat;
    result[key] = {termStat};
    return result;
}, {});

console.log(userData);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Minor suggestion. Save ref to `info` and use it across. That would make your code easy to read. `const info = user.data.result[0].info; result[info.uid] = { termStat: info.attr.termStat}`

Comment: @Rajesh agree, the array op have is nested multiple levels which for sure code be accessed/de structured in better way, the intention here was just to suggest the reduce function.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the key as the `userid`.

```js
const arr = [{
  data: {
    result: [
    {
      info: {
        uid: 12,
        attr: {
          termStat: 'foobar'
        }
      }
    }
    ]
  }
}]

const userData= arr.map(user => ({
  [user.data.result[0].info.uid]: { 
    'termStat': user.data.result[0].info['attr'].termStat 
  }
}));

console.log(userData)
```

Comment: It will return an array again, what op is asking for is a map

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the userid as a variable putting it in a square brackets and assing it a value if I understand it correctly

```
[user.data.result[0].info.uid]: {'termStat': user.data.result[0].info['attr'].termStat}
```

Comment: I think this is a good place where destructuring arguments would actually help. `(acc, { data: { result: { info}}}) => ({...acc, [info.uid]: info['attr'].termStat)`